# Array Initialisation is not working correctly?

Tags: c++, arrays

Say I am giving the input

> 5 10

I am expecting the output to be...

> -5 6 7 8 9 10

But I am actually getting the output...

> -5 6 7

Here's my code.

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
  int main()
    {
    int prime[1000];
    int m,n;
    cin>>m>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n-m+1;i++)
      {
       prime[i]=m;
       m++;
      }
    for(int i=1;i<=n-m+1;i++)
       {
       cout<<prime[i];
       }

return 0;
```

}

Comment: You are changing `m` in the first for loop.  You need to reset it back to what it was before the loop.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you change m?
Just start from i=0 to n-m and the next number you need is i+n:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int prime[1000];
    int m,n;
    std::cin>>m>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<=n-m;i++) 
    {
        prime[i]=i+m;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=n-m;i++) 
    {
        std::cout << prime[i] << ' ';            
    }

    std::cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using m in the for loop but you're updating its value and in each iteration it has a different value. You can use another temporary variable to store the value of m as in the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     int prime[1000];
     int m,n, l;
     cin>>m>>n;
     l = m;
     for(int i=0;i<=n-m;i++)
     {
         prime[i]=l;
         l++;
     }
     for(int i=0;i<=n-m;i++)
     {
         cout<<prime[i];
     }

     return 0;
}
```